# Using the woocommerce API using PHP

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using the woocommerce API for the first time and need some help with it.

I thought I'll start easy and use it to just get the site title returned.

I read the documentation at https://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#view-index-list but its too complex and doesn't provide details about the first steps I need to do to connect to the API.

I have enabled the REST API on my woocommerce powered site.

My questions are,

1. How do I connect to this API ? The documentation tell me to run
   `<?php print_r($woocommerce->get('')); ?>` but where am I supposed
   to run it ?
2. How do I authenticate myself with the keys that are
   generated by the API ?

I appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This link should be able to help youL https://www.skyverge.com/blog/using-woocommerce-rest-api-introduction/
What you need to understand is that the keys are your authentication. Kind of like an entry password to your site's API. Then you need to acknowledge the key within the code for your api request followed by your API requirements. Hope this helps.